# Black screen when upgrading RAM in Z690 motherboard

Tags: bios, motherboard, ramdisk

I have a Gigabyte Z690 motherboard with 16 GB RAM (2x8 GB) model Kingston FURY Beast DDR5 4800MT/s CL38. When I added 32 extra RAM of the same model (2x16 GB) along the 2x8 GB modules, the screen never wake up. If I use only the 2x16 GB without the 2x8 GB the PC works fine. However, 4 RAM boards do not work at the same time.

I have made sure to follow the correct steps for their installation (remove power supply, install them in their corresponding slots, try different settings in the BIOS).

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by upgrading the BIOS. Do this process carefully as it may break the motherboard. I did the following steps:

- Format a USB to FAT32
- Go to Gigabyte Z690 official web and download the latest bios version (in my case for the Z690-UD-AX-rev-1x board).
- Unzip and coy the *.FXX file into the USB, then rename this file to GIGABYTE.bin
- Turn off the PC, disconnect the power supply, put USB in the port that is labeled as BIOS (on the back), then turn on the power supply, turn on the PC and access to the BIOS.
- In the BIOS go to the Q-FLASH menu, which is in the bottom right side tabs (for the Gigabyte Z690 board).
- Go to Upgrade BIOS section and select the USB, then click on the GIGABYTE.bin file and continue.
- The PC will turn on and off a few times, DO NOT TURN OFF!, leave it until the PC boots the OS.

Comment: Instead of linking to an external source you cannot cite, you should describe in detail, what exactly you did.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to edit it